# How to install Rocks Cluster using WiFi (Intel Wireless N)

Tags: centos, wifi, intel

I only have access to WiFi (not ethernet) and need to install Rocks Cluster, which is based on CentOS. I keep getting stuck on the network configuration.

I installed Debian on the same computer using WiFi by skipping network configuration at install time and adding WiFi drivers via a flash drive.

The laptop is a Dell D830 Latitude with an Intel Wireless-N card.

Comment: Please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R Sure. I just realized the Ubuntu OS was already overwritten, so I can't do it this second but it's Broadcom / Intel and I will get this info as soon as I can get the computer to load an OS.

Answer (score 0):

I installed rocks clusters before.The rocks cluster installation  was using text mode and defined wired Ethernet.My suggestion : you can configure wifi using commnad line after finished The Rocks cluster installation.You should check wifi driver on rocks cluster based on Centos.You can seach how to configure wifi using command line.Rocks cluster didnt have GUI mode to configure WiFI.

Comment: Thank you. If I can get it to finish installing without a network then I can do this, but I can't see how to get past the network configuration screens at install time (?). I will try again right now.